# What can I do to make this code work?

Tags: python

I'm a computer science student and for most of our classes we used Java and now we're taking one where we have to use python, so I was hoping that you could tell me why the `grid[i][j].append('Q')` never takes effect and what I can do to make it work. The purpose behind this assignment is to generate Eight queens puzzle instances and then eventually return the solutions. Please help me, here is what I have so far:

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in grid:
    for j in grid:
        if i==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j].append('Q')
pprint.pprint(grid)
```

Modification: I want to have Q printed in a separate column each time.

So I tweaked the code just a bit to get it printed into the column but the problem is it's printing in the same column each time, the reason I was using random was to try to get in a separate one each time. Here's the code that's at least letting me print in one column:

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        if j==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j]=('Q')


pprint.pprint(grid)
```

I'm assuming I have to increment j somewhere between the two loops and I've tried putting it in different places but it is not working.

I THINK I GOT IT, just had move the insertpoint variable into the for loop

I'm really close to what I want thanks to the code by Dave below but I'd prefer for the output not to have the 'Q's all in the same row. Can you please help me, I tried a bunch of different stuff but only to get further away from it

Here's the code and output:

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in range(0,8):
    for j in range(0,8):
        if i==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j] = 'Q'
pprint.pprint(grid)

    [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

Comment: In each column, I am expecting to have one 'Q' printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `i` and `j` do not iterate over integers so they cannot be used to index into the array.

You could try:

```
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        if i==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j] = 'Q';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this program.

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in range(0,8):
    for j in range(0,8):
        if i==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j] = 'Q'
pprint.pprint(grid)
```

Comment: -1: the code is correct but an Answer should contain an Explanation. Especially when someone is still learning the language in question.