# need a little help finishing this code

Tags: python

I'm a computer science student and my assignment is to make random 8x8--queens puzzle permutations and have Queens in different columns but not all in one row. I'm really close to what I want the code to do but I have the 'Q's all in the same row which I do not want. Can you please help me, I tried a bunch of different stuff but only to get further away from it

Here's the code and output:

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
for i in range(0,8):
    for j in range(0,8):
        if i==insertPoint:
            grid[i][j] = 'Q'
pprint.pprint(grid)

    [['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
     ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

Comment: What is a "queens puzzle permutations and have Queens in different columns but not all in one row"? Do you mean you need to swap queens until there no queens on the same row?

Comment: I want one queen in each column, so that there are eight queens in the grid. None of them can be in the same row. So one queen would be at 5,7 so no queen could be in the fifth column or the seventh row

Comment: Seems like other people from your class have been posting this same problem today.

Comment: What about your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930278/what-can-i-do-to-make-this-code-work

Comment: Nobody was replying to the modified part so I started a new thread, sorry not sure how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
import pprint
import random
grid = [['-']*8 for n in range(8)]
for i in range(0,8):
    insertPoint = random.randrange(1,8)
    for j in range(0,8):
        if j==insertPoint:
            grid[j][i] = 'Q'
pprint.pprint(grid)

[['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['Q', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q'],
 ['-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-', '-'],
 ['-', 'Q', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q', '-']]
```

Comment: OMG! thank you, can't believe just had to change one letter!

Comment: Oh lol j and i. I thought it was [row][column]

Comment: To OP, either this code does not do what you think it does, or, you don't need the second for loop - you might as well say ``grid[insertPoint][i] = 'Q'`` eliminating the ``j``-loop and all references to ``j``.

Answer (score 0):

Note, for each row there has to be a queen.

Also note having placed a few queens, you can only use empty columns, so keep track of columns used up.

And finally, keep track of diagonals used up so that you can eliminate new queen against a hashtable instead of having toquery against all the queens placed.

Keeping these in mind, the best data structure is to use a few sets - and not a matrix, for the board and queen positions.

Here's a code that takes all these ideas and generates the non-attacking queen positions.

```
n=8

rows=set(range(n))
cols=set(range(n))
diags1=set(range(2*n+1))
diags2=set(range(2*n+1))

entries=set()

count=0

def Possibilities():
    r=count
    for c in cols:
        if r-c+n-1 in diags1 and r+c in diags2:
            yield ((r,c))


def AddQueen(r,c):
    global count
    entries.add((r,c))
    rows.remove(r)
    cols.remove(c)
    diags1.remove(r-c+n-1)
    diags2.remove(r+c)
    count+=1

def RemoveQueen(r,c):
    global count
    entries.remove((r,c))
    rows.add(r)
    cols.add(c)
    diags1.add(r-c+n-1)
    diags2.add(r+c)
    count-=1

solcount=0

def PrintSoln():
    for r in range(n):
        for c in range(n):
            print(' Q' if (r,c) in entries else ' .',end='')
        print()
    print()

def Solve():
    global solcount
    for (r,c) in list(Possibilities()):
        AddQueen(r,c)
        if count==n:
            solcount+=1
            PrintSoln()
        else:
            Solve()
        RemoveQueen(r,c)

Solve()

print(solcount)
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok then it's simple: at grid[j][i] = 'Q', save the row into another array which stores every row taken by a queen. Also, you need to make a while loop because you need to iterate until the random generator finds a good value:

```
// I don't know python, so the syntax might be weird
bool takenRows[8] = {false};
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    int currentRow = 0;
    do
         currentRow = rand(0, 8); // 8 exclusive
         if (!takenRows[currentRow])
             grid[i][currentRow] = 'Q';
             takenRows[currentRow] = true;
    while(takenRows[currentRow])
```

Beware of how your grid manages rows and columns with the grid[][].

Comment: Id you "don't know Python"; why provide code that is C?

Comment: Because it looks like pseudo code.

Comment: It **does not** look like pseudo code at all; It has types and semantics that assume C;

Comment: Oh come on, you understand what I mean. It is a basic code that anyone who knows a functional programming language can understand. It does not use hard C/C++ semantics to grasp.

Comment: Also, if no one would have answered him, than my code would have been better than nothing.

Comment: I just don't think answering a Python questin with C is all that helpful :) But all good :)